# smooth curve on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Say i have the smooth manifold $ M=\Re^2 $, and a smooth curve $\gamma:\Re \to M$ with $\gamma(t)=(t,t)$.

Can i draw this curve to the manifold without the use of any chart?

Maybe it sounds a silly question, but i ask it because if $\Re^2$ is only a smooth manifold why should its points be located at certain places as if it were a    vector space? I don't think it has enough structure to have lets say (2,0) at the right of (1,0)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R^2$ ? What is the problem drawing a straight line on the 2D plane ? And what is a "chart" ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comment in José's answer, I think what your confusion is.

Let $\phi\colon U =\mathbb{R}^2 \to M=\mathbb{R}^2$ be a chart of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You really have to distinguish the domain $U=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, even though they are the same set. In this example they are the same set, but in general there not.

Example. The chart $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2: (r,\theta)\mapsto(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$. In the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ your curve will be the straight line with slope $1$, the first bissectrice.
But in the domain $U$, the $(r,\theta)$ coordinate-space, the associated coordinate curve will look like a horizontal line ($\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$).

A similar thing holds for all coordinate charts: your curve $\gamma$ will always be the same line in the manifold, but the associated coordinate curve $\phi^{-1}\circ\gamma$ in the domain of the chart, depends on the choice of coordinates.

Comment: you said in the manifold my curve will be a straight line with slope 1. what i ask is why

Comment: Because in $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ we describe points standard by their cartesian coordinates. Said in a different way: if it is not mentioned, we use the identity chart $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y)$.

Comment: I also would like to mention that a point itself doesn't depend on the coordinates itself. For instance, if you look at the point $(1,1)$ (cartesian coordinates), you can  _describe_ it as $(\sqrt{2}\cos\frac{\pi}{4},\sqrt{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{4})$ (polar coordinates), but it will be the same point! Both couples of numbers describe the same dot in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

But $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set, independently of the manifold structure that we decide to endow it with. And on the specific set, we have the usual Cartesian coordinates to represent its points. So, in particular, yes, $(2,0)$ is to the right of $(1,0)$ (with respect to these coordinates). Besides, what have “left” and “right” to do with charts?

Comment: but you choose to represent its points with the usual cartesian coordinates and then you saw a straight line.If  you choose another representation you will see another line, but  this means you see no unique line and since we speak about the  curve  on the  mnfld  not on a chart this cant be true because the curve has to be unique. So the representation you chose to make was actually picking a cart, and i said i want the curve on the mnfld, not on a chart.